# Verwendung von »existenziell« für Sachen

Tags: word-usage, single-word-request

Sowohl laut Duden wie auch laut Wiktionary bezeichnet das Wort *existenziell* etwas, das für das (menschliche) Leben oder Dasein wichtig ist. Demnach wäre es also falsch, wenn man schriebe:

> Der Motor ist ein existenzieller Bestandteil des Autos

da ein Auto ja nicht lebt, sondern eine Sache ist. Welches Wort kann ich hier also statt *existenziell* verwenden, um auszudrücken, dass ein Auto nicht ohne Motor existieren kann? Ich dachte an *substanziell* als Alternative, aber das scheint mir etwas anderes, mehr Quantitatives zu bezeichnen.

Comment: Ich hätte spontan zu "essenziell" gegriffen, aber [die Duden-Bedeutungsübersicht](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/essenziell) passt leider auch nicht zu 100 Prozent... "wesentlich / entscheidend"?

Comment: Ich bin davon überzeugt, dass z.B: "*Einnahmen sind existenziell für ein Unternehmen*" ein gültiger deutscher Satz und auch eine valide Verwendung von "existenziell" ist. Die Einschränkung auf "Leben oder Dasein" halte ich für zu eng, zumal "Existenz" lt. Duden durchaus auch *Vorhandensein* und *Bestehen* bedeutet. Warum die Einschränkung dann beim Adjektiv gemacht werden soll, ist unlogisch. Allerdings ist ein Auto auch ohne Motor immer noch ein Auto, ein Unternehmen ohne Einnahmen bald nicht mehr. Von daher ist "essentiell" vielleicht doch besser ;)

Comment: @tohuwawohu Bei "essentiell" steht doch "wesentlich"?

Comment: Stimmt - da war ich wohl zu erbsenzählerisch (hoffentlich gibts das Wort...)

Comment: Wie wären _unabdingbar_, _unerlässlich_ oder _unverzichtbar_?

Comment: Danke schon mal für die Antworten bis hier her, aber nach meinem dafürhalten ist ein Auto ohne Motor eben kein Auto mehr, sondern nur eine Karosserie, da sich ein Auto nach meinem Verständnis eben dadurch auszeichnet, sich durch Motorkraft fortzubewegen.

Comment: @scienceponder - Dann kommen wir nicht zusammen, denn das ist eben Ansichtssache. MMn am ehesten so Das *Konzept* eines Autos ist ohne Motor nicht vorstellbar. Ein *konkretes* Auto sehr wohl.

Comment: Klar ist das Ansichtssache, wir müssen in dem Punkt auch nicht unbedingt zusammen kommen, er ist aber für das Wesen meiner Frage entscheidend. Auf deinen Edit hin: Klar kann man so sehen, alles Definitionssache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diese Adjektive drücken aus, dass etwas ein das Wesen einer Sache grundlegend ausmachender Bestandteil ist:

**konstitutiv; integral; elementar; fundamental**

(Kraftwerk könnten daraus bestimmt ein neues Stück machen.)

Okay, 'integral' ist unter Umständen ein Wackelkandidat, aber ohne das Wort würde sich die Liste ja gar nicht mehr reimen.

Comment: Servus und willkommen beim Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Du kannst eine [Tour] der Seite nehmen. Fragen darüber, wie sie funktioniert, beantwortet dir das [Help]. Ein wenig mehr Erklärungen anstatt nur eine Wörterliste hinzuwerfen wird hier gerne gesehen.

Comment: Hey, ich hab immerhin noch einen lauwarmen Witz mit reingeworfen!

Comment: Danke! Fundamental trifft aus meiner sicht die Funktion des Motors hier perfekt!!!!

Answer (score 4):

*Existentiell* bedeutet in meinem Sprachgebrauch "Wenn das nicht mehr bei **was** ist, gibt es das **was** nicht mehr" - Also grundlegend notwendig (oder eben "Vorbedingung") für die Existenz bzw. das "Sein" des "was". ("Sein" hier nicht im Sinne von "Dasein" und damit "Leben", sondern eben "Existenz")

Nehmen wir z.B. lt. Duden etwas Lebendiges:

> Regelmässiges Einatmen ist für den Menschen existenziell wichtig

Funktioniert auch für ein nicht-Lebewesen:

> Regelmässige Einnahmen sind für ein Unternehmen existenziell wichtig

(mit Absicht gleich sortiert)

Ohne Einnahmen wird es das Unternehmen mit großer Sicherheit nicht bzw. nicht mehr lange geben. *existenziell* funktioniert also auch prima für Dinge (So man denn ein Unternehmen als solches bezeichnen kann). Duden ist hier wohl mit seiner Begrenzung auf "Lebendiges" ein wenig zu einschränkend.

Oder was aus der Physik:

> Die molekularen Bindungskräfte sind existenziell für die Materie, wie wir sie kennen

(Funktioniert also auch für was Kleineres...) Auch die Materie hört auf zu existieren, wenn die Teilchen nur noch wild rumflitzen...

> Der Motor ist existenziell für das Auto

Funktioniert allerdings nicht richtig - Das Auto hört nicht auf zu existieren, nur weil man den Motor ausbaut. Auch ein Auto ohne Motor wird wohl allgemein als Auto betrachtet.

*existenziell* kann man also meiner Meinung nach nur verwenden, wenn durch die Tatsache, dass die Vorbedingung nicht mehr gegeben ist, die *Existenz* des jeweiligen Objekts bedroht oder nicht mehr gegeben ist.

Für Auto und Motor würde ich lieber *essentiell* nehmen.

Comment: Wenn Du erzählst, Du hättest ein Auto gekauft, und unterschlägst, dass es keinen Motor hat, dann wirst Du merken, dass es dann nicht mehr als richtiges Auto verstanden wird - im Kontrast zu einem Autoradio oder der Rückbank.

Comment: @userunknown Nur wenn ich damit heimfahren wollte ;). Du willst jetzt sicher nicht behaupten, dass ein VW Käfer, aus dem du den Motor ausbaust, sich in derselben Sekunde in einen Haufen lackiertes Blech verwandelt, oder? Es ist hinterher immer noch ein Auto, nur eben ohne Motor.

Comment: Wir könnten an der Stelle anfangen zu philosophieren, ob ein Mensch, der aufhört zu atmen, immer noch ein Mensch ist. :D

Comment: Ein Haufen lackierten Blechs ist nicht dasselbe wie ein Auto ohne Motor, aber ein Auto ist etwas anderes als ein Auto ohne Motor - wie ein Mensch ohne Herz etwas anderes als ein Mensch ist.

Comment: "Die Existenz geht der Essenz voraus" (Sartre) - Das gilt für mich auch andersrum - Wenn die Essenz weg ist, hört für mich die Existenz nicht auf. Der Mensch ohne Herz wird wahrscheinlich aufhören zu existieren, in den Käfer baue ich einfach einen neuen Motor ein und habe ein funktionierendes Auto.

Comment: Vielen dank für die interssanten Antworten. Auto und Motor sind in meiner Frage selbstverständlich nur Platzhalter für einen viel abstrakteren wissenschaftlichen Zusammenhang. Dennoch kann meiner Meinung nach ein Auto eben nicht ohne Motor existieren, da es ohne eben kein Auto mehr ist, sondern nur noch eine Karosserie ohne die definierende Fähigkeit eines Autos, sich aus eigenem Antrieb heraus zu bewegen. Selbiges trifft auch für mein "eigentliches" Problem zu. "Essentiell" ist mir eben aus genau dem Grund, dass das Auto ohne Motor eben kein Auto mehr ist, zu schwach.